How do Transformers prisons work?
I know that there are prisons in the Transformers universe (I think at least most of the Transformers continuities have one) but how do they work? What are the cells like? What about defenses? But my main question is this. I saw somewhere that said that Transformer prisons work by removing the prisoner’s brain, but still keeping them alive, is this true? I’d like to know…

Hello! Welcome to the site. Have a look at our [tour] and [help] since you are new here. As to your question, is there a specific versions of Transformers you would like to see an answer from (e.g., movies, cartoons, comics). The answers may be different based on the source and leaves this question a bit broad.

Duplicate of "Do Transformers have prisons?".

In the G1 cartoon series, Starscream steals some prisoner "kernels" (I forgot what they called them) and put them in some old WW2 equipment to create the Combaticons.
